# Crawler4j gives null as parentURL and zero as parentDocID in url redirection

Tags: java, web-crawler, crawler4j

I am using the latest version of Crawler4j to crawl some feed URLs. I've passed some seed URLs along with the doc ID and I have also set the depth to zero as I only want the content of that page.

The problem is that I am not able to get the parentdocid and parent URL for those seed URLs. I'd like to know the redirected URL associated with the original URL.

I'm using `page.getWebURL().getParentUrl();` to get the parent url.

e.g. http://telegraph.feedsportal.com/c/32726/f/568297/s/18b0dd9a/l/0L0Stelegraph0O0Cculture0Cmusic0Cmusic0Enews0C87789850CNeil0EYoung0Eto0Erelease0Eautobiography0Bhtml/story01.htm and doc id 10

for more detailed description http://code.google.com/p/crawler4j/issues/detail?id=163

Anyone got a similar issue?

I've tried again with different URL but still same result.
    controller.addSeed("feeds.reuters.com/~r/reuters/bankruptcyNews/~3/es0kEUT8gI0/",321);

OUTPUT:--

ParentDocId 0 
DocID 322 
Parent Page null

```
UPDATE:--------
```

I went through the crawler4j code and temporarily fixed my issue.

```
-------- PageFetcher.java ---------

if (header != null) {

String movedToUrl = header.getValue();
movedToUrl = URLCanonicalizer.getCanonicalURL(movedToUrl, toFetchURL);
fetchResult.setMovedToUrl(movedToUrl);                                                            
webUrl.setParentUrl(webUrl.getURL()); //My Custom Code to add Parent URL.
/*This won't work due to collision with next            
document ID which needs to be unique.
webUrl.setParentDocid(webUrl.getDocid());*/

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I was dealing with the same problem recently so I figured I'd put my solution up in case others come along looking for a solution.

Basically the parentURL and parentDocId that get set on a redirect page aren't supposed to be the URL and DocId of the original page, they get set to the parentURL and parentDocId of the original page.

This is because the parentURL and parentDocId are supposed to represent the page that the current page was linked from, not a page that it was redirected from.

Changing this behaviour could normally cause some possible issues, but in our case as we're only crawling single pages, and not performing long depth searches through links from pages, so the parentDocId and parentURL will never get used.

With this information in mind, I was able to find a solution.

Simply override the `handlePageStatusCode()` method of the WebCrawler and add the following lines:

```
if (webUrl.getParentUrl() == null) {
     webUrl.setParentUrl(webUrl.getURL());
}
```

With this code, whenever a new page is handled the `parentUrl` will initially be set to `null`, but now it will be set to the url of the current page. As said earlier, when a redirect page is added to the queue, its `parentUrl` is set to the `parentUrl` of the page is was redirected from, therefore when the redirect page is handled, the `parentUrl` will already be set so it wont be changed.

Now when you handle the page in the `visit()` method or wherever else, you will be able to extract the original url from the `parentUrl`of the pages `WebUrl`.

Hope this information helps someone out!